# How do something when JSON is loaded

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have JSON connection, how do something when JSON String is loaded, and if not - expect for full loading. In this case after loading I want to show a toast message. Usually there is a delay of a couple of seconds when the information is loaded.

```
Alamofire.request("https://codewithchris.com/code/afsample.json").responseJSON{ response in

        if let value = response.result.value{

            let json = JSON(value) 
            \\ view.makeToast("JSONIsLoaded", duration: 2, position: bottomLayoutGuide, title: "title", image: UIImage (named: "logo.jpg"), style: style ) { (success: Bool) in}
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Search on `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: question is confusing. What do you want to do after its loaded? Are you asking you want to show an activity indicator while its loading?

Comment: @Martheli, take some value from json and show it. Just want understand in general

Comment: @rmaddy , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is how you would use Alamofire to automatically validate the response. If the response comes back within the 200 range, you can run some code and if it comes back anything else it will fail and you can catch any errors there. You can also start and stop an activity indicator in the following code so that the user gets some notice that a background action is taking place.

```
//start activity indicator here

Alamofire.request("https://codewithchris.com/code/afsample.json").validate().responseJSON { response in

    switch response.result {

    case .success(let value):

          if let json = JSON(value) {
            // Do whatever you want with json
            //hide activity indicator here
           }
           else
            {
             //No data returned
            }

    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
        //hide activity indicator here

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire requests in background . so you will get response in in backgroud thread as well. but we should refresh or update ui in main thread as there will be lag or may not find any update on ui with code in backgroud threads. So use DispatchQueue.main.async{  ui updating code }